# AWS EKS secrets store provider - Failed to fetch secret from all regions: name

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am using the [AWS secrets store CSI provider](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws) to sync secrets from the AWS Secret Manager into Kubernetes/EKS.

The `SecretProviderClass` is:

```yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: test-provider
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: mysecret
        objectType: secretsmanager
        jmesPath:
          - path: APP_ENV
            objectAlias: APP_ENV
          - path: APP_DEBUG
            objectAlias: APP_DEBUG
```

And the Pod mounting these secrets is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  serviceAccountName: my-account
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 2
  containers:
    - name: dotfile-test-container
      image: registry.k8s.io/busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: "/mnt/secret-volume"
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: test-provider
```

The secret exists in the Secret Provider:

```json
{
  "APP_ENV": "staging",
  "APP_DEBUG": false
}
```

(this is an example, I am aware I do not need to store these particular variables as secrets)

But when I create the resources, the Pod fails to run with

```
Warning  
FailedMount  
96s (x10 over 5m47s)  
kubelet            

MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secret-volume" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod pace/secret-dotfiles-pod, 
err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to fetch secret from all regions: mysecret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error message is *very* misleading. The problem in my case was due to the type of the `APP_DEBUG` value. Changing it from a boolean to string
fixed the problem and now the pod starts correctly.

```
{
  "APP_ENV": "staging",
  "APP_DEBUG": "false"
}
```

Seems like a bug in the provider to me.

Comment: Thx! had the same for DB_PORT, it was 3306 and in Plaintext it was 

    ...,"port":3306,...
So after changing to 

    ...,"port":"3306",...
it worked. Still showing port | 3306 in Key/value view of Secret Manager though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by altering list of environment variables inside referenced `SecretProviderClass` while attempting to run another deployment. Deleting this object and creating it back again solved the issue.